# How to change view depth?

Tags: ios

Is there any way to make one view appear over another in the code? like adjust its depths or layer so its displayed above the other? I have two textviews and I want one to be shown but the other is currently covering it. I can't edit this in storyboard either because I created both views in the code and not in storyboard. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you'd rather not mess with z-positions, you could always use the following methods:

```
- (void)exchangeSubviewAtIndex:(NSInteger)index1 withSubviewAtIndex:(NSInteger)index2;
- (void)bringSubviewToFront:(UIView *)view;
- (void)sendSubviewToBack:(UIView *)view;
```

Note that sending a subview to the front or back will bring it all the way to the front or back, not just by 1. You could also just remove the view and insert it where you want using:

```
- (void)insertSubview:(UIView *)view atIndex:(NSInteger)index;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can change `UIView` layer z order with following code.

```
[yourView.layer setZPosition:10];
```

It is applied to all objects inherited from `UIVIew`.

Comment: Thanks. And just for future reference, does a higher number mean higher priority or lower to be shown?

Comment: Yes it is correct, higher the number bring it to front.